# Talend: set db_connection parameters as variables

Tags: postgresql, variables, talend

I am migrating tables from an old database to a new database (I am using PostgreSQL).

My goal is; Once I export the job, I want to prompt the user to enter the database connection details (host, port, database name, etc..) when he want to execute the Job.

I did like the following but it didn't work;

context Variables:
[image]

database connection settings:

[image]

Sample job:

[image]

input Component Details:

[image]

The Following  exception is raised :

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "context_db.db_name"      does not exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your job :

Your need to reference your db_name variable by adding the prefix `context` like this : `context.db_name` (and not `context_db.db_name`).

Because you defined your context group before creating the connection, typing `context.db_name` as your database will interpret it as a string literal (and not a context variable), that's why you're you're getting an error as it's looking for a database with the name "context_db.db_name", which doesn't exist. In order to reference an existing context variable, click "Export as context" when you're on the connection window, then select "Reuse an existing repository context" :

[image]

Next choose your context group, and map each connection parameter to an existing context variable from the droplist. When you finish, you'll see that your connection is using the context variable `context.db_name` as its database name.

In order to prompt the user for a value, you need to activate the checkbox next to the variable (Activate prompt on variable), which you've already done.

Comment: Thanks that helps!!